# Error while running make autoannotate sundance_apps 4.3.7

Tags: unix, makefile, sundance

I am trying to install opinionfinder and I getting stuck when i am trying to make autoannotate for sundance apps.

The error log I get is huge and it has all undefined reference errors.

The first line says in function 'my_init_sundance(sunstr,sunstr)' and a list of undefined reference errors.

Anyway i can solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did the whole process with the help of christopia , i even did the tweaks but i was on 64 bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to compile autoannotate you must make sure Sundance compiled successfully. Check that your sundance-4.37/bin contains: aslog nlp prepro

In order for Sundance to compile on my 64 bit machine I had to edit the Makefile files in both src and include and add -m32 to the CFLAGS variable (or the NormalCC). Also down after the shared_lib_linux: target. Since I am on OSX I also had to add -dynamic flat to NormalOpts and LIBS.